# Removing an element when date goes by

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove an element from the html after the current date of today goes past the start date of the creation of the item, but it's not removing the element at all.

```js
for (var x = 0; x < ListLength; x++) {

startDate = document.getElementById("StartDatelabel" + x);

                        var today = new Date();
                        var dd = today.getDate();
                        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
                        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                        if (dd < 10) {
                            dd = '0' + dd
                        }
                        if (mm < 10) {
                            mm = '0' + mm
                        }

                        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
                        startDate.setAttribute("min", today)
}

   //Remove New icon
                        $(function(){
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('.notify-badge').each(function (i, val) {
                                var currentDate = new Date();
                                var date = new Date(jQuery(val).text().split(' - ')[0]); // or 1 for second date
                                if (startDate < currentDate) {
                                    jQuery(val).parent().remove();
                                
                                 }
                            });
                        });
                        });
```

```html
   <span class="notify-badge">NEW</span>
```

Comment: Your snippet does not include an element with `id="StartDatelabel"`.

Comment: Hi, I have a backend loading the data into the textview with the id "StartDateLabel", so once the data has been loaded in to the for example, 2020-06-06, the notify-badge should be removed.

Comment: If you using backend to update your element make sure the JavaScript is re-run after your element updated, u'r using `$document.ready()` it's mean only run once when your page is done loaded, not in everytime your DOM updated.